# size() function doesn't with with js selector / is

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
<input type="checkbox"> a<br />
<input type="checkbox"> b<br />
<input type="checkbox"> c<br />
<button>Size</button>

<script>
$('button').click(function() {
    alert($('input').is(':checked').size());
});
</script>
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8f7stx5/

When I click on the "Size" button I get a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('input').is(':checked')`  will return flag true false based on checkbox value and using method `.size()` will return undefined on bool value(you can see the error in console).

also use `.length` instead of `.size()` as size is deprecated in version 1.8:

```
$('input:checked').size()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/susmswk4/)**

Comment: Or, preferably, `length`.

Comment: @lonesomeday: indeed... :)

Answer (score 1):

`.is()` returns a Boolean of whether the element fulfills the selector. Try using `.filter()` instead:

```
alert($('input').filter(':checked').size());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.length` property is the preferred way:

```
$('input:checked').length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/a8f7stx5/2/)